# When moving to Eclipse J2ee from regular, do I need to uninstall?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I currently have the standard dev eclipse 3.5.2, but now need to do some jsps etc, so want to move to the j2ee version.

Can I install the j2ee version right over my old one, or do I need to uninstall?  I guess another option might be to get the WST packages and install those directly?

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest and best IMO is to open Help > Install New Software, select the Galileo update site and install the web and EE features. You also might consider using the latest release, 3.6 (Helios).

Comment: thanks, this worked perfectly.  I didn't try all the features yet, everything downloaded and installed without a hitch.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW you can easily run multiple eclipse versions on one PC. I run Ganymede, Galileo, Helios, Aptana RadRails and Flash Builder w/o issue (5 instances). I find this is easier to manage than one instance loaded up with all the add-ons I need for all of them

Comment: this is a great idea.  unfortunately, where i work, they have blocked off downloading (part of the fun of working at a big bank).  I tried downloading from several sites, but didn't work.